# "Found x matching results in y miliseconds" in EF6 LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I've tried to look for this solution, which supposed to be simple in my opinion, but couldn't find the right one for Entity Framework and LINQ. So, either I'm missing something very trivial or I'm not able to word my requirement properly.

Anyway, in a couple of older ASP/ASP.NET projects I see the output being produced to a website visitor, such as "Found 1 matching results in 1320 ms". I would like to have this kind of information being shown on a new EF6 MVC 5, Razor project as well. At least for debugging purposes. But I can't find a way of implementing this in my C# code.

Hopefully, this is something simple to do.

Thank you, guys!

P.S. Milliseconds part is more important to me.

Comment: Use a performance timer between the service method call and use that. `var timer = Timer.Start(); var results=Service.search(); var ms = timer.Stop().Duration;` EF6 does not provide you query execution time info as far as I know. We usually have a helper Timer delegate `var ms = Timer.Measure(()=> { //code to measure the execution time });` for this purpose.

Comment: If you're only really after this for debugging purposes, take a look at either [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) or [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) which provide this sort of detail, and more for you.

Comment: Thank you, cackharot. Unfortunately, no matter what Timer library I use, I get this error: "'System.Timers.Timer' does not contain a definition for 'Measure'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of Stopwatch and ViewModels to display this:

```
public class MyCustomViewModel
{
  public TimeSpan QueryDuration { get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<SomeModelClass> Persons { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult MyActionMethod()
{ 
    var vm = new MyCustomViewModel();

    Stopwatch _watch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    vm.Persons = executeQueryHere().ToList();
    vm.Queryduration = _watch.Elapsed;
    return View(vm);
}
```

Please note that this might go wrong, if you don't materialize your queries, due to deferred execution - you want to call `.ToList()` or `AsEnumerable<>`
This is just a dummy code to give you one simple way to do it.

**EDIT:**

Other third-party-libraries which do the job way better then I could are [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) (Example at www.nerddinner.com - top left of the screen) and [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/).

Comment: Thank you, Serv! Your solutions does work, however, I'm having troubles with actual logic of that solution - where to use it and how to keep the result in MVVM. 

Anyway, despite that, you answered the question.